# Coverity CMake build error

Tags: cmake, coverity

I could not get CMake to build with Coverity.  I am new to CMake and not sure how to fix this problem.  I am able to build sample program with this command:

```
cov-build --dir . gcc sample.cc -o sample.o
```

However, when I tried to build with CMake

```
cov-build --dir . cmake ../
```

I am getting the no emit error:

```
Coverity Build Capture (64-bit) version 2017.07 on Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
Internal version numbers: 7a4de27b47 p-milo-push-30112.654


-- Using Build Type provided on command line
-- Library config4cpp Found
-- CONFIG4CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS=/opt/config4cpp/include
-- CONFIG4CPP_LIBRARIES=/opt/config4cpp/lib/libconfig4cpp.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hitp6130/pulsar

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.

 For more details, please look at:
    /home/hitp6130/pulsar/build/build-log.txt
```

Comment: `cmake` doesn't build the project - it just configures it. For build configured project you need to run `make` from the build directory.

Comment: alright, thanks for the answer.  I tried the following and still got the "No files were emitted" warning: cmake . then cov-build --dir . make

Comment: Probably, you CMake project actually don't compile any file. Without viewing that project (in form of [mcve]) *we can only guess*.

Comment: my project can build fine using cmake then make-j;  the executable was created using these 2 commands.  I just need to incoorporate coverity to do thread analysis

Answer (score 0):

"Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation."

My experience with this error, is that the compiler is not configured. What is the command you're using to configure the compiler in Coverity?  Will you post the contents of your _cov_install_\config\coverity_config.xml?

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE coverity SYSTEM "coverity_config.dtd">
<coverity>
<!-- Version 2017.07 -->
    <cit_version>1</cit_version>
    <config>
      <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-gcc-config-0/coverity_config.xml</include>
      <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-g++-config-0/coverity_config.xml</include>
      <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-gcc-config-1/coverity_config.xml</include>
      <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-gcc-config-2/coverity_config.xml</include>
      <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-g++-config-

Comment: <include>$CONFIGDIR$/template-ld-config-0/coverity_config.xml</include>
    </config>
</coverity>

Answer (score 0):

Arcoding to the coverity [guidline](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Configuring-Your-Compilers-for-Coverity-Analysis), I think `cmake` is not the simple case, and you need the full version of the command as bellow:

```sh
cov-configure  --template --compiler <compiler-binary-name> --comptype <compiler-type>
```

Example:

```sh
cov-configure --config cc-config.xml --template --comptype gcc --compiler cc
cmake ..
cov-build --dir <build-dir> --config cc-config.xml make
...
```

- `cc-config.xml` is the configuration file which coverity generate. You can use different name as you need.